# Prevent onBlur event occurency while opening new tab in browser

Tags: javascript, events, onblur

Let's consider simple HTML input field

```
<input type="text" onblur='alert("hello");' />
```

when mouse is in this input field and you try to open new tab in browser (Chrome, IE, ...),
onblur event is being triggered. I don't want to trigger onblur event in such manner. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Can you use `onfocusout()` ???

Comment: onfocusout event is not fully supported by browsers (as far as I know).

Comment: to lose focus you will have to click outside on something else, it's not a great solution but you can put a listener on body for any click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement)** to check if the element has indeed lost focus in DOM. (**[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement#Browser_compatibility)** is quite wide as well.)

Your code could look like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" onblur='blurred(this);' />
```

JS

```
function blurred(elem) {
    if (elem != document.activeElement) {
        alert("Bye !");
    }
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/HANc2/)**.